# Protected abstract vars in Scala can be implemented public?

Tags: scala

Could someone explain why scala would allow a public variable, to satisfy the implementation of an abstract declared Protected item? My first assumption is that the compiler would complain, but I created a small test to see if this worked, and to my surprise it does. Is there an advantage to this? (perhaps this is normal in OOP?) Any methods to avoid the accidental pitfall?

```
object NameConflict extends App {

  abstract class A {

    protected[this] var name:String

    def speak = println(name)
  }

  class B(var name:String) extends A {  //notice we've declared a public var

  }



  val t = new B("Tim")
  t.speak

  println(t.name) // name is exposed now?
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's normal and as in Java. Sometimes it's desirable to increase the visibility of a member.

You can't do it the other way around and turn down visibility in a subclass, because the member can by definition be accessed through the supertype.

If invoking a method has terrible consequences, keep the method private and use a template method that can be overridden; the default implementation would invoke the dangerous method.

```
abstract class A {
  private[this] def dangerous = ???
  final protected def process: Int = {
    dangerous
    template
  }
  protected def template: Int = ???
}
class B extends A {
  override def template = 5
}
```